# How do I find out if a fragment has been back pressed /popped from stack?

Tags: android, fragment

I have an ACTIVITY that hosts two fragments A and B. By default fragment A is hosted. Fragment B is started from fragment A. When user presses back in fragment B, and assuming some data was changed, first I kill fragment B using following code in B:

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fragmentManager != null) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    }
}
```

**My question:**

How do I know that fragment B has been 'killed' from fragment  A, or even from ACTIVITY?
I want to refresh data in A when B is killed.

Something like

```
if (B.isKilled()) {
    refreshDataInA();
}
```

I want to be able to do both from ACTIVITY and fragment B.

Thanks !

Comment: you can refresh data in ```onCreateView``` callback of fragment A. Or use interfaces for activity fragment communications

Answer (score 1):

In your A fragment, the onResume method add

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(B.isDetached()){
            refreshData();
        }
    }
```

try it.